# MapReduce with put in HBase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-zookeeper, put

I have these version of libraries with ${hbase.version} equals to 2.1.0

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-mapreduce -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-mapreduce</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and the following code is how i configure the job

```
InputStream hbaseSite = SampleUploader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hbase-site.xml");
    InputStream pathCoreSite = SampleUploader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("core-site.xml");
    InputStream pathMapRedSite = SampleUploader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mapred-site.xml");
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.addResource(hbaseSite);
    conf.addResource(pathCoreSite);
    conf.addResource(pathMapRedSite);
    Path inputPath = new Path(args[0]);
    String tableName = args[1];
    Job job =  Job.getInstance(conf, NAME + "_" + tableName);
    job.setJarByClass(SampleUploader.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputPath);
    job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Uploader.class);
    // No reducers. Just write straight to table. Call initTableReducerJob
    // because it sets up the TableOutputFormat.
    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(tableName, null, job);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

when i run the code i have the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:114)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(TableOutputFormat.java:182)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:280)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:146)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1570)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1567)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1567)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1588)
at com.package.test.SampleUploader.main(SampleUploader.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:219)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.close(ConnectionImplementation.java:1920)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionImplementation.java:310)
... 17 more
```

I noticed that if you comment on the line

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(tableName, null, job);
```

the connection to zookeeper is carried out without problems. But when I insert the aforementioned line I have the above error. Depends on what?
To consider that I am trying to execute a mapreduce that executes put in hbase by reading from file

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I've changed version of org.apache.hbase.hbase-mapreduce package in pom from 2.0.0 to 2.1.0